# Not able to copy data in hdfs with hdfs dfs commands

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to copy data over hdfs. but none of the commands not working for me.

I followed an [online tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php) to install a single node cluster. it got installed correctly because `$jsp` command showed me all 6 jobs. but when I'm trying to copy a file over to hdfs it's showing me an error.

the command I'm running is

```
hduser@naren-Vostro-3560:~$ hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/nare/Desktop/data/first.txt /app/hadoop/tmp
```

Error

```
14/12/30 02:18:09 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
copyFromLocal: '/app/hadoop/tmp': No such file or directory
```

I have given all the permissions to input the file (first.txt)

```
naren@naren-Vostro-3560:~$ ls -al /home/naren/Desktop/data
total 3612
drwxrwxr-x 2 naren naren    4096 Dec 30 01:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 naren naren    4096 Dec 30 01:40 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 naren naren  674570 Dec 30 01:37 first.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 naren naren 1423803 Dec 30 01:39 second.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 naren naren 1573151 Dec 30 01:40 third.txt
```

the permissions to the hdfs folder also look right to me

```
hduser@naren-Vostro-3560:~$ ls -l /app/hadoop
total 4
drwxr-x--- 5 hduser hadoop 4096 Dec 26 01:22 tmp
```

I'm new to Hadoop and Linux and got stuck here.
also I tried creating a new directory with

```
hduser@naren-Vostro-3560:~$ hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hduser/sample
```

and it didn't create any directory for me.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Thanks in Advance!!

Hadoop Version: `Hadoop 2.5.2`
OS: `Ubuntu 14.04`

Comment: Can you add the error message to your hadoop fs -mkdir command as well as add your core-site and hdfs-site xml configurations? They'll be helpful to see if you configured hdfs correctly.

Comment: `hadoop fs -mkdir`  is not giving me any error only Hadoop Deprecated message and when i'm `hdfs dfs mkdir` no errors. but the directory not created.

Comment: core-site and hdfs-site.xml is same as http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php

Comment: You need to make sure /app/hadoop is created in hdfs, not the local fs. In your check for the directory you use ls -l which checks on the local filesystem which is separate from the hdfs namespace. Try hadoop fs -ls /app/hadoop. If it's not there then create it with hadoop fs -mkdir.

Comment: @snkherv, you should post an answer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to make sure /app/hadoop is created in hdfs, not the local fs. In your check for the directory you use ls -l which checks on the local filesystem which is separate from the hdfs namespace. Try hadoop fs -ls /app/hadoop. If it's not there then create it with hadoop fs -mkdir. – snkherv